# A separation property

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

Does anyone know the name of the following somewhat unusual property of the topological space $(X,\tau)$? (It makes me think of the $T_0$ separation axiom.)

For each $x\in X$ and for each finite subset $F$ of $X$ such that $x\not\in F$, there exists a neighborhood $U_{x,F}$ of $x$ such that $U_{x,F}\cap F=\emptyset$.

Comment: It is equivalent to T1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T_0$ is too weak.  Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by the basis consisting of intervals $(a, \infty)$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Take $x = 0$; any neighborhood of $x$ must contain the interval $(0, \infty)$. Therefore, if $F = \{1\}$ for instance, there is no neighborhood of $x$ disjoint from $F$.

As mentioned in the comments, the condition you describe is equivalent to $T_1$, and you can easily show this. A $T_1$ space $X$ is such that for each $x \ne y \in X$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ not containing $y$, and a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ not containing $x$. Assume $X$ is $T_1$. Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary, and $F$ be a finite set with $x \notin F$. For each $y \in F$, select neighborhood $U_y$ of $x$ that misses $y$. Since the collection $\{U_y\}_{y \in F}$ of neighborhoods of $x$ is finite, the intersection of its elements is a neighborhood of $x$. And, that intersection misses each point of $F$, since each point $y$ of $F$ is excluded from $U_y$. That your condition implies $T_1$ is trivial to show; for $x \ne y \in X$, take $F = \{y\}$ to find a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that misses $y$, and take $F = \{x\}$ to find a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ that misses $x$.